# Android offline voice recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, cmusphinx, htk

I already use HTK (Hidden Markov Model Tool Kit) for recognizing specific commands 
used to control my Android application, but in this case I need to pass some voice data to a server and that may consume more time.

To prevent this latency, I am thinking about using [pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download/) to recognize the voice data locally with the Android application so that I won't need to pass that audio to the server.

If this is a good idea, is it easy to learn pocketsphinx from scratch? Also, what are advantages and disadvantages of both techniques (server-based and local voice recognition), and which one is better?

Comment: Can you please make the question clearer and format a bit for readability?

Comment: It should look better now.

Answer (score 0):

CMUSphinx is definitely a great idea, it has a number of advantages over HTK:

- Better license
- Works offline on Android
- Fast
- Supports multiple languages out-of-box
- Easier to use and learn

You definitely should try Pocketsphinx, for more information see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/